# System.__ComObject when outputting to CSV

Tags: powershell, outlook

I'm running some PowerShell to try and get a list of email addresses ever sent "To" from a users sent items in Outlook.

It works perfect when doing the users inbox as I use "SenderEmailAddress", but when I try and use "To" from the users sent items, the output comes back as `System.__ComObject` and I can't get it into a string / text for the CSV.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | Out-Null

$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application

$mapi = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

$Items = $Mapi.Folders.Item("UsersMailboxGoesHere").Folders.Item("Sent Items").Items;

$Items | select To | Export-Csv C:\outs\Export.csv
```

Comment: `To` is an object that contains multiple properties where `ToString()` is just returning its type.  You need to delve further on what you need to pick out of `$Items.To`

Comment: So I need basically everything that it contains. According to the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/mailitem-to-property-outlook)

It says that To returns semicolon-delimited String list of display names for the To recipients for the Outlook item, which is what I need - the entire string

Comment: Look at `$Items.To | Get-Member`.  VB and powershell are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Led me to some better documentation. This works.

```
 $Items |
     select Recipients |
     foreach {$_.Recipients} |
     select Address |
     Export-Csv 'C:\outs\Export.csv'
```

Comment: As a point of improvement: `$Items.Recipients.Address | Export-Csv -Path C:\outs\Export.csv`  Automatic enumeration is a hell of a drug.

Comment: Beware that member enumeration requires PowerShell v3 or newer. To simplify your code you could replace `select Recipients | foreach {$_.Recipients}` with `Select-Object -Expand Recipients`, though. You may also want to add the parameter `-NoTypeInformation` to `Export-Csv`.